# Eventfinder API: start_date parameter doesn't work

Tags: api, rest, service

I am trying to get results from the Eventfinder API. It's a REST based service.
I want to get events from tomorrow.

But instead I will always get events from today (probably because default time is `now`).

Let's assume we have Friday the 2014-03-28 and I want events of Saturday the 2014-03-29.

When I request this url:
`http://api.eventfinder.co.nz/v2/events.xml?rows=1&start_date=2014-03-29` I am getting events of the 2014-03-28.

For me it's not clear how to set the time, after I read the documentation on [Eventfinder.co.nz](http://www.eventfinder.co.nz/api/v2/events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have found a solution by myself.

It's important setting the `end_date` parameter too. If the `end_date` is **not** set, the event must happen at the *current date* **AND** a the *date* where the `start_date` is set.

This is an example usage, getting events of *Saturday* the *2014-03-29*.

```
 http://api.eventfinder.co.nz/v2/events.xml?rows=1&start_date=2014-03-29&end_date=2014-03-30
```